# How to trigger an html button and its onclick function with a hardware keyboard key?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, addeventlistener

I'm a newbie to coding, and this topic is probably very common, but it has me pretty confused.

I have a button:

```
<button onclick = typeWriter()>/click</button>`
```

My function:

```
var myArray = ['such', 'something else', ]; 
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]; 
var i = 0;
var speed = 55; 

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < rand.length) { 
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML += rand.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed); 
  }
}
```

How do I add a keyboard key like the spacebar as an event listener or something similar, so that when I press the spacebar (and not in a text box), it presses the button and triggers the function? A simple vanilla javascript answer would be preferable, since I don't get jQuery.

Would it be better to simply add script that triggers myFunction with the spacebar rather than going through triggering the button? And if so, how do I program that?

BTW: I'm trying to do this for mobile, using an iPad keyboard. Will that change anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener on `window` if you want to trigger your function everywhere of your html.

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        //your function here
    };
};
```

Here you can find all key codes for keyboard: https://keycode.info/

Comment: @HelloWorld please edit your question to add all the relevant code. The comments section is not suited for that.

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. You should be using `e.key === 'Enter'` instead. Also, check out this other tool: https://keyjs.dev

Answer (score 1):

- don't use inline JS
- Use `addEventListener()`
- Use `Event.key` to determine the pressed key
- Use a helper function to determine if the current `Event.target` is a FormElement

```js
// Function to detect if el is a form element
const isFormElement = el => /^(input|textarea|select|button)$/i.test(el.nodeName);

// Example function
const myFunction = ev => console.log("HELLO!");

// Find buttons in DOM
const EL_myfn = document.querySelectorAll('.js-myFunction');

// Trigger directly on buttons click
EL_myfn.forEach(el=> el.addEventListener('click', myFunction));

// And on keydown
window.addEventListener('keydown', ev => {
  // If spacebar is hit, and we're not inside a forminput element
  if (ev.key === " " && !isFormElement(ev.target)) {
    myFunction();
  }
})
```

```css
textarea{width: 100%;}
```

```html
<button class="js-myFunction">Click me! (Console  should log)</button>
<div>press spacebar here (Console should log)</div>
<textarea>press spacebar here (Console should not log!!)</textarea>
```